# Querying multi level associations in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have associations as below:
Location Class

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
end
```

Item class

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
  belongs_to :category
end
```

Category class

```
class category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
end
```

Now i want to query Location.categories (show all categories of location items).
How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be as simple as this:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
  has_many :categories, :through => :items
end
```